# jQuery intermittently not applying after refresh, observed "from memory cache" vs "from disk cache" in Network tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm encountering an intermittent issue while integrating jQuery into my Angular project. I'm attempting to convert a HTML template that use jQuery. I've imported the necessary jQuery files into my angular.json, but I'm facing a problem sometimes the jQuery functionalities apply correctly, but upon refreshing the page, they fail to do so. Strangely, after repeated refresh attempts, the jQuery functionalities might start working again without changing my code.

I've noticed in the `Network` tab when the jQuery functions apply correctly, the resources are labeled as `from memory cache` next to a 200 status code. However, when the jQuery fails to apply, the resources are labeled as `from disk cache`.

I attempted to debug my `theme.js` file to see what happen

```
sticky: function () {
    console.log($('.header-sticky .sticky-area').length);
    $('.header-sticky .sticky-area').each(function () {
        // code
    });
}
```

The `console.log` statement indicates whether the jQuery has been successfully applied or not. If successful, it returns a count of 1; otherwise, it returns 0.

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually using AngularJS (Angular 1)? Please tag only the relevant version. Syntax varies and that gets confusing.